# Why is data sent across the network converted to network byte order?

Tags: c, sockets, ipc

I'm not sure how to use `hton()`. The theory is that any data sent over the network should be in network byte (i.e. big-endian) format. Suppose client A supports big-endian and B supports little-endian. I'm sending data from A to B and the data is read as multibyte. Then in the network we need to convert data to network byte order using `htonl()` and `htons()`. Since client A is already big-endian, `htonl()` and `htons()` return the same output. But B is little-endian, so those functions reverse the order. Given that, how can we say that adhering to a common format (i.e. big-endian) is a solution to the problem when big- and little-endian machines need to communicate?

Answer (score 7):

I'll try it the other way, showing the whole flow:

Sending `0x44332211` over the wire always happens as `44 33 22 11`. The sender's `htonl()` ensures that, either by reverting the order of the bytes (on LE machines) or by just leaving them the way they are (on BE machines). The receiver turns the `44 33 22 11` into `0x44332211` with `ntohl()` - again, either by reverting them or leaving them.

The mentionned functions `{hton,ntoh}{l,s}()` help programming in a portable way: no matter if the program tuns on a LE or BE machine, they always work the way they should. Thus, even on BE machines the functions should be called, even if they are noops.

Example:

A (BE) wants to send `0x44332211` to B (LE).

1. A has the number `0x44332211` in memory as `44 33 22 11`.
2. A calls `htonl()` as the program has been written to be portable.
3. The number is *still* represented as `44 33 22 11` and sent over the wire.
4. B receives `44 33 22 11` and puts it through `ntohl()`.
5. B gets the value represented by `11 22 33 44` from `ntohl()` and puts it into the respective variable - which then results to `0x44332211` as wanted.

Again, the need for always calling these function saves you from thinking about which kind of machine you are programming for - just program for *all* kinds of machines and call each of these function when they are needed.

The same example can be expressed without knowing if A or B are BE or LE:

1. A has the number `0x44332211` in memory.
2. A calls `htonl()` so that the number is sent as `44 33 22 11` over the wire.
   Whether this is done by reverting or by leaving it is determined by the endianness of host B.
3. B receives `44 33 22 11` and puts it through `ntohl()`. This one reverses it or not, depending on the endianness of host B.
4. B gets the value `0x44332211` as wanted.

Comment: i have few more doubts.does hton() always means convert to Bigendian format and ntoh() means always convert to little endian format.Because host can be either little endian or bigendian.Is it because since B in the above case is in LE format that in step 4 ntohl(44 33 22  11) gives 11 22 33 44? if B was in BE format then does the result of ntohl(44 33 22 11) would be 44 33 22 11?.Rest is clear for me.Thanks for a great explanation.

Comment: @SubiSuresh "hton" means "host to network", "ntoh" means "network to host". Whether they convert and to which format depends on the native data format. On a BE machine, they both do nothing, on a LE machine, they both convert.

Comment: @gigl>please dont mind as i am asking the same doubt,which is still not clear to me.i undrestood till step 4.B receives 44 33 22 11.So in the memory location of B it will be stored like 11 22 33 44(say starting address is 100,then 100 contains 11,102 contains 22 and 104 contains 33 and 106 contains 44, because B is LE and while reading ,B will read from the highest memory address ie 106 like 44 33 22 11.So what is the need of ntohl() in the step 4 ,you are mentioning.Pls clarify this.it will be helpful to me as a starter

Comment: @SubiSuresh In step 4 the function/macro does the reverting, as host B is LE. Again: You need the call everywhere, because you want to program portable, and the compiler and its ennvironment know whether to actually do something or not.

Comment: I want to ask you one detail for clarity: In step 3, how is number `44 33 22 11` sent: would we first send 11, then 22, then 33, then 44 (which has a natural view of sending a flow from left to right) and so the receiver would first receive 11 then 22 then 33 then 44, or is it the other way around? Also, when we send byte such as `0x78` which in binary would be `0111_1000`, would we start sending the right most bit first?

Comment: @mercury0114 As I explicitly mentionned the splitting to bytes, the bytes are sent in the given order, so `44 33 22 11`. Concerning the bit order, it's something what you don't have to worry about as a programmer and what may be different from one technology to the other.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking that client B seeing the bytes in "reversed order" means that they're wrong. The bytes will be in reverse order compared to client A, but that's because client A interprets integers backwards from client B; both will still interpret it as the same number in the end. For example, one machine would represent the number 4 as `00 00 00 04`. The other would represent it as `04 00 00 00`, but both would still see it as a 4 -- if you add 1 to it you're going to get `00 00 00 05` and `05 00 00 00`, respectively. The `hton`/`ntoh` functions exist because there's no way to look at a number and know if it's big- or little-endian, so the receiver can't be sure which way to interpret the bytes

Comment: Yes offcourse ,i am thinking the same.so if the A send  in the format 0x44332211,B reads it as 0x11223344.Then what is the need of hton().if B can read it in the correct format

Comment: @SubiSuresh The receiver reads the data one byte at a time, in whatever order the sender sent it in. If A sends `44 33 22 11`, B is going to read `44 33 22 11`, and it needs to know what endianness those bytes are in (which it does because all network data is big-endian). Since B is a little-endian host, it will flip the bytes and store `11 22 33 44` in memory, which represents the same number as A's `44 33 22 11` do, because A and B interpret numbers differently

Comment: @Micheal Morozek> i didnt understand exactly what you meant by the line The hton/ntoh functions exist because there's no way to look at a number and know if it's big- or little-endian, so the receiver can't be sure which way to interpret the bytes.Could you pls explain the same.

Comment: @SubiSuresh `11 22 33 44` is a valid number in both big- and little-endian. In big-endian it translates to 287454020 in decimal; in little-endian it's 1144201745. The system needs to know which endianness the number is in to know what its actual value is

Comment: @Micheal Morozek>OK OK .now i got it.So you meant to say that all the hosts are programmed in such a way that to reverse the data ,once data is received.Because network data will always be in the Bigendian format.Am i right?.Thats why we made  the rule that network data should be  in the network byte order as the standard format.

Comment: @Micheal Morozek>Could you pls check the comment?What i understood is right or wrong,so that i can go ahead?

Comment: @SubiSuresh: everyone agrees that if you have to read a 4-byte integer off the network, the MSB arrives first, then the middle two, and finally the LSB.  The software on the receiving machine knows unambiguously how to reassemble the data received over the network into the correct host format, using `ntohl()` in this case.  On some machines, that can be a no-op; on others, it requires some bit twiddling.

Comment: @SubiSuresh "all the hosts are programmed in such a way that to reverse the data ,once data is received" is wrong. All hosts are programmed  to call the `ntoh/hton` functions, yes. But only those hosts reverse who need to, who are different from network byte order - the LE ones. The BE ones do the call in order to have the programs portable.

Comment: @glglgl>I will explain to you by example.Consider server A(Bigendian) sending the 4 byte integer data 0x44332211 to B(which is little endian).So B inteprets it as 0x11223344,which is a different number.So now as per the theory we have to use network byte order over the network.so htons(0x44332211) will still give the same 0x11223344 as A is bigendian.Now my question is B inteprets it as a different number 0x11223344.So what is the use of htonl() here?Pls help @glglgl

Comment: @SubiSuresh: You'd use `htons()` to transform words from host-order **to** network order and `ntohs()` to transform **from** network order.  They essentially to the same but it's a matter of style and documentation.  In your case, `ntohl(0x11223344)` on machine B will give you `0x44332211` and that's what machine A sent.  So there's your use of `ntohl()`